# VMWare ESXi + LetsEncrypt - SSL certificate renewal

Tags: vmware-esxi, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, ovh

With **VMWare ESXi** (I'm running ESXi 6.7), I'm regularly go through an SSL issue. Chrome & Firefox do not allow self-signed certificated provided by internal VMWare system.

In my case, the only way to access to VMWare Sphere Web Client is to use Safari (on macOS) and allow manually certificate as a trusted certificate.

[image: SSL error in chrome]

The point is to declare signed certificate.
As VSphere Client is only for administrator use, I'd rather not paying a ~100$-a-year third-part signed certificate.

Until a few months ago, I used [ZeroSSL](https://zerossl.com/) which is not totally free anymore (blocked after 3 renewals). I was following [these instructions](https://fabien.io/certificat-lets-encrpyt-sur-un-hote-esxi/)

Is there a way to use [Let'sEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/fr/) process to get a valid signed certificate and push it my VMWare Server ?

Comment: As an aside, you can get a one year commercial SSL certificate for less than $4.00 USD.

Comment: Previously, I had bad experience on this → some of SSL certificates discouters have "exoctic" root CA, and my websites went as failure in chrome i.e.

Comment: I have about 100 services behind SSL encryption, 4... makes a lot ;-)
And letsencrypt can be automated easily is most of the cases (web servers)

Answer (score 4):

3 main steps for setting up this.

### 1. Let's Encrypt certificate generation with DNS challenge.

Default [challenge process](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/) with let's encrypt is [HTTP-01 / acme-challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#http-01-challenge) file generation.
It's not convenient with ESXi use.

I switch to [DNS-01 Challenge](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/challenge-types/#dns-01-challenge) which is [compliant with my DNS provider](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/dns-providers-who-easily-integrate-with-lets-encrypt-dns-validation/86438).
I use `certbot` tool.

You can install it with

```
apt install python3-pip
pip install certbot
```

> I found a [dedicated python certbot tool extension](https://certbot-dns-ovh.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for challenge automation.
> See [OVH specific extension](https://certbot-dns-ovh.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [complete tutorial](https://buzut.net/certbot-challenge-dns-ovh-wildcard/)
> Specific tool is `pip install certbot-dns-ovh`

---

The final command is `certbot` itself :

```
certbot certonly -d mydomain.com
```

> Specific version for OVH is `certbot certonly -d mydomain.com --dns-ovh --dns-ovh-credentials ~/.ovh-api`
> You'll have to create .ovh-api file with [these instructions](https://buzut.net/certbot-challenge-dns-ovh-wildcard/)

Thanks to his, I've got quickly a list of `.pem` files

### 2. Certificate format transform

Certificate are directly generated in .pem format so **you do not need to change format**. You just have to rename files

```
cp fullchain.pem rui.crt
cp privkey.pem rui.key
```

> Be carefull, do not use `cert.pem` but `fullchain.pem`.
> **`cert.pem` is not compliant with ESXi**

### 3. Renew certificate on VMWare esxi

- On ESXi host, backup your old certificate

  ```
  cd /etc/vmware/ssl/
  mv rui.crt rui.crt.`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`.bak
  mv rui.key rui.key.`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`.bak
  ```

  > Actually, you should backup these 2 files on your workstation.
  > `scp myhost:/etc/vmware/ssl/*.bak ./`
  > If ssl certificates are not compliant with vmware host client requirements, web ui will not start again... particulary boring and stressfull to fix  ...
  > If you need to rollback and reset ssl, you can use `/sbin/generate-certificates && reboot` command
- From your workstation:
  Replace your certificate
  `scp rui.key rui.crt myhost:/etc/vmware/ssl/`
- On ESXi host, restart the host
  `reboot`

Comment: Is there really no less disruptive way to start using the new certificates than to reboot the host?

Comment: Aha, [here](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-vSphere/6.7/com.vmware.vsphere.security.doc/GUID-A261E6D8-03E4-48ED-ADB6-473C2DAAB7AD.html) is the answer: "Alternatively, you can put the host into maintenance mode, install the new certificate, use the Direct Console User Interface (DCUI) to restart the management agents, and set the host to exit maintenance mode." Not quite as disruptive as a reboot, but still a real pain.

Comment: @MichaelHampton You don't need to reboot nor to put your host in maintenance. Simply restart the relevant services... e.g. hostd and vpxa.

The downside of the DNS challenge is that you only perform it once hosts are already added to vCenter, so initial trust still needs to be verified using thumbprints.

Answer (score -2):

Restarting the Management agents in ESXi (1003490) https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/1003490
using DCUI or SSH shell